# Creating a standalone tool script in a CommonJS project

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

I have a bigger node project (TypeScript, NextJS), and I want to add a utility script I can run manually in that project. Let's presume it's cleaning up some files. I want to run it with a command like `ts-node tools/cleanup.ts`.

But I always end up with a syntax error and `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`
I tried to access a dependency like this:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';` //  Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

and like this (which feels wrong b/c I think I don't want to create a global script file):

```js
// Added to avoid "cannot be compiled under '--isolatedmodules' because it is considered a global script file"
export {}; // SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
const fs = require('fs');
```

I don't want to modify the `tsconfig.json`, e.g. to set `"type"` to `"module"`, because that would affect the whole project, and all I want to do is squeezing in a small script with dev dependencies at most.

Is there any way to achieve this without changing the `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json`, which is looking like that:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Could you try using `ts-node -O '{"module": "commonjs"}'`? https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/313#issuecomment-343698812

Comment: @VaiTon Yeah, that did the trick! If you provide an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thank you so far! The url is really helpful anyway. This `ts-node-script` mentioned there seems to be another interesting approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I replied in one of the comment (and thanks for confirming that it works!) there is [this issue in the ts-node repo](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/313#issuecomment-343698812) that talks about this and this works:

```
ts-node -O '{"module": "commonjs"}'
```

Another approach mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/313#issuecomment-747668038) is using `ts-node-script`.